# Implementing "MySQLicious" solution to store tags in MS-Access

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I just want some suggestions and opinions on implementing "MySQLicious" (if it is at all possible) on this article "http://howto.philippkeller.com/2005/04/24/Tags-Database-schemas/". I could see how it is done in MySQL but the database I was given is in Access so I want to keep it that way. I'm not sure if Access can stores multiple tags.

I have a database of research papers that I would link keywords to. Each research paper may have many tags. I considered the Normalizing with intersection table (aka the **Toxi** - 3 tables) approach. I would have a research table (ID, Name, Date Published) and a tag table(tag_id, name), and a tag map table. However, it seems a bit expensive. I'm more familiar with MySQL than Access and would like some insight to whether it is possible to implementing "MySQLicious" or that I should stick to the **Toxi** approach.

Comment: Please try to ask a concrete question. You can implement any and all of these in Access, and the advantages and disadvantages are not very different than that of MySQL, nor is the implementation.

Comment: I just skimmed the linked article but it seems to me `tags` is just a text field. You can do that in any DBMS.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth MySQLicious only supports mysql atm. I just want to know if anyone has attempted this in Access. It seems like you have to go from scratch with this approach from Access.

Comment: Be advised that the `MySQLicious` approach is a lot more complicated to do properly than the article implies. For example if you used it's code to search for the tag `Access` you would also get anything tagged `MS-ACcess`, `Network Access` and `Keyless Access` (really anything with the word access in it or as part of it).

Comment: It's just an SQL query and table schema! Access supports all of the operators that are used there. @SunKnight That's easily fixed by using a separator between tags.

Comment: @K.U What exactly is it that you think MySQL supports that Access does not? It is just a text field with wildcard searches. There is nothing special there.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth agreed. Just pointing out that the article itself is pretty simplistic and should not be taken as some special wisdom.

Comment: We agree on that. Honestly, the article is pretty badly written, and doesn't talk about performance in the way it should (with indexes, fragmentation when changing tags, etc.). If it did, it would be pretty clear that MySQLicious is not a very good plan.

Comment: Are there any resources that you recommend on this topic? Would it be a good idea to put all tags in a text field with separators or create a tag table?

Comment: Tag tables are the way to go, since that allows you to take advantage of indexes, is more properly normalized, and is likely faster when updating and less likely to cause fragmentation when adding and removing tags. That Toxi structure looks somewhat right, except you can omit the ID on the tagmap table, and just use a composite primary key with the 2 remaining fields (making the entire table the primary key). This of course assumes that you can't tag one bookmark with the same key multiple times.